# Delete users from Apple Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I hired "Developer Carl" to develop an iphone app, and I tested the app on my iphone using TestFlight. Since I didn't know much about this, I told *Developer Carl* to set everything up.

Two years later, I hire another programmer to debug some issues. When I go to my App Store Connect to add the new programmer, this is what I see.

The issue is that I'm tagged as "Marketing", which means that I can't delete anyone. Developer Carl is "Admin" and "Account Holder". Not only that, only Developer Carl knows who user "Jan Ysa Vegas" is.

Can I delete these users? Or can I delete the whole thing so that the new programmer sets this up correctly?

[image]